# parse.com push notifications framework not working with ionic framework Xcode project?

Tags: ios, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am looking to get push notifications working with the ionic framework and parse.com.

I tried adding the push.com framework to the Xcode project, but as soon as I do I can no longer compile the project (throws up about 45 errors). This is before I even add / change any code, I simply include the parse.com framework on the build list.

Any help greatly appreciated as always :)

Errors listing below

```
-bsvxvbqqiuaufjbgslrfogfllszq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.app/Test

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      +[PFPush handlePush:] in Parse(PFPush.o)
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      +[PFPush handlePush:] in Parse(PFPush.o)
  "_CATransform3DIdentity", referenced from:
      -[PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView setState:] in Parse(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o)
  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
      -[PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView setState:] in Parse(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransaction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPayment", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPaymentTransactionObserver.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
      ___22-[PFCommandCache init]_block_invoke in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PFCommandCache dealloc] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils saveToKeychain:data:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils saveToKeychain:data:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils deleteFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kCAGravityResizeAspect", referenced from:
      -[PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView initWithFrame:] in Parse(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o)
  "_kCATransactionDisableActions", referenced from:
      -[PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView setState:] in Parse(PF_EGORefreshTableHeaderView.o)
  "_kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection", referenced from:
      -[PFHTTPCommand scheduleInCurrentThread] in Parse(PFHTTPCommand.o)
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPAttemptPersistentConnection", referenced from:
      -[PFHTTPCommand scheduleInCurrentThread] in Parse(PFHTTPCommand.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils getKeychainQuery:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils loadFromKeychain:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      +[PFInternalUtils saveToKeychain:data:] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: You probably added a linker flag...  make sure you add all required frameworks, and Facebook too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need to add the Social.framework to your project.

Comment: Thank you - this set me on the right direction to getting things sorted. :) I just searched for all the libraries it appeared to be missing and added them. Cheers.